# converting pandas dataframe with categorical values into binary values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to convert categorical data into binary to be able to classify with an algorithm like *logistic regression*. I thought of using OneHotEncoder from 'sklearn.preprocessing' module but the problem is the dataframe entries are A, B pairs of arrays with *different* lengths, each row has pair of same-length arrays not equal to array lengths in other rows.
**OneHotEncoder** does not accept dataframe like mine

> In [34]: data.index
>
> Out[34]: Index([train1, train2, train3, ..., train7829, train7830,
>   train7831], dtype=object)

```
In [35]:  data.columns

Out[35]:  Index([A, B], dtype=object)

SampleID                      A                                B
train1      [2092.0, 1143.0, 390.0, ...]          [5651.0, 4449.0, 4012.0...]
train2      [3158.0, 3158.0, 3684.0, 3684.0....]  [2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0...]
train3      [1699.0, 1808.0 ,...]                 [0.0, 1.0...]
```

So, I want to highlight again that each A and B pair has the same length but the length is variable across different pairs. Dataframe contains numerical, categorical and binary values.
I have another csv file with the information about every entry type. I read the file filter out categorical entries in both columns like this:

```
info=data_io.read_train_info()
col1=info.columns[0]
col2=info.columns[1]
info=info[(info[col1]=='Categorical')&(info[col2]=='Categorical')]
```

Then I use `info.index` to filter my training dataframe

```
filtered = data.loc[info.index]
```

Than I wrote an utility function to change dimensions of each array so that I can encode them later

```
def setDim(df):
    for item in x[x.columns[0]].index:
        df[df.columns[0]][item].shape=(1,df[df.columns[0]][item].shape[0])
        df[df.columns[1]][item].shape=(1,df[df.columns[1]][item].shape[0])

setDim(filtered)
```

Then I thought to combine each pair of arrays into 2-row matrix so that I can pass it to encoder then to separate them again after encoding, like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

def makeSparse(df):
   enc = OneHotEncoder()
   for i in df.index:
     cd=np.append(df['A'][i],df['B'][i],axis=0)
     a=enc.fit_transform(cd)
     df['A'][i] = a[0,:]
     df['B'][i] = a[1,:]

makeSparse(filtered)
```

After all these steps get a sparse dataframe. My questions are:

1. is this a right way to encode this dataframe?(I highly doubt it)
2. if no, then what alternatives do you offer?

   Thanks a lot for your time helping me.

Comment: The answer to (1) strongly depends on what the rows actually *represent*. In any case, the scikit-learn convention is that one column represents one feature, and each feature must be present in each sample.

Comment: I see, let me elaborate on that. Each pair of A and B vectors have the same number of features but they are not the same across the other pairs. Each row has different features. So if the features are not the same across  the rows, encoding cannot be applied, right?

Comment: If you want to learn from data, you need consistent features throughout your set. You'll have to "fill in" (impute) the other features, but then the columns have to be consistent.

Comment: @larsmans my dataframe contains observations from different kind of experiments. It's a cause-effect relationship with one column being cause the other effect or vice-versa. How to deal with this heterogeneous dataset? Can encoding be applied after the transformation suggested by Jeff below?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's still too fuzzy. May I make a guess: is each row a set of integers that denote that some event occurred, while all events not listed did not occur?

Comment: @larsmans each row is a pair of 2 equal-length arrays. Entries in one array are observations of an experiment so they are different values of some feature(event). Entries in the dataframe's other column's array are either cause or the effect of the first. So basically each row represents outcomes of 2 events and the task is to predict the cause-effect relationship. See this link, please
[kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/cause-effect-pairs)

Comment: Ah. But did you check the [baseline code](https://github.com/benhamner/CauseEffectPairsChallenge)? It shows how to do feature extraction on this set.

Comment: @larsmans Sure I checked, but that code doesn't take into account the type of input values(i.e. numerical, binary or categorical). I wanted to encode categorical values before feeding them to classification algorithm

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice way to transform your data to a better repr to deal with; uses some
neat apply tricks

```
In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
                               A                  B
train1         [2092, 1143, 390]  [5651, 449, 4012]
train2  [3158, 3158, 3684, 3684]       [2, 4, 2, 1]
train3              [1699, 1808]             [0, 1]

In [73]: concat(dict([ (x[0],x[1].apply(lambda y: Series(y))) for x in df.iterrows() ]))
Out[73]: 
             0     1     2     3
train1 A  2092  1143   390   NaN
       B  5651   449  4012   NaN
train2 A  3158  3158  3684  3684
       B     2     4     2     1
train3 A  1699  1808   NaN   NaN
       B     0     1   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This is really neat, thanks! The question remains: can the OneHotEncoder be applied to this transformed dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Some 9 years later or so, as redirected to this thread from the official Pandas docs (namely the cookbook), I came upp with a probably even neater implementation of the transformation from the most upvoted answer.

To go from this:

```
        A                          B
train1  [2092, 1143, 390]          [5651, 449, 4012]
train2  [3158, 3158, 3684, 3684]   [2, 4, 2, 1]
train3  [1699, 1808]               [0, 1]
```

To this:

```
            0       1       2       3
train1  A   2092.0  1143.0  390.0   NaN
        B   5651.0  449.0   4012.0  NaN
train2  A   3158.0  3158.0  3684.0  3684.0
        B   2.0     4.0     2.0     1.0
train3  A   1699.0  1808.0  NaN     NaN
        B   0.0     1.0     NaN     NaN
```

...one can simply use:

```
df.transpose().unstack().apply(pd.Series)
```